# Background-size transitions in Chrome 51 - a bug or a feature?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

Background-size transitions are no longer working in [Chrome 51](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.rs/2016/05/stable-channel-update_25.html). I know that it was never supposed to work (see [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)), but it did and still many people used it. I'm talking about percentage transitions on hover.

I'm wondering if this is a bug in the new Chrome (which is possible, since this version brings a lot of new stuff), or they've decided to remove that transition for good?

No issues in other browsers.

---

```css
div {
  background: url(http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Super-Mario-no-longer-the-007.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 276px;
  width: 460px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover {
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

### UPDATE

As @Paran0a noticed, it works fine with vendor-specific prefix, so it's probably a bug (submitted a bug-report):

---

```css
div {
  background: url(http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Super-Mario-no-longer-the-007.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 276px;
  width: 460px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: -webkit-background-size Works though.

Comment: Just to be clear which version of chrome are you on? (I'm on Version 51.0.2704.63 m ) This example works for me https://jsfiddle.net/dz4L9nyh/

Comment: @Paran0a, Omg, I'm sooo sorry. I've tested the vendor-specific version, but forgot to include the actual transition... :facepalm:

Comment: Btw. I'm using 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit) on Linux.

Comment: Something unspecified that changes, or quits working altogether, is never a bug. You should never use unspecified and undocumented properties.

Comment: @Rob True, though in that case the bug is the fact it works (not really, of course, because no browser devs really live by the W3C specs), along with all the vendor-specific properties, right? But they were used everywhere, in a way forcing many of those properties to make the official specs (look at CSS3 and the period before it launched). I'm not worried about using the bleeding edge stuff myself (I'm aware of what can happen), but I was just curious if anyone here knows what's going on in the Chromium team regarding this issue.

Comment: Sorry if the previous comment is confusing - I think background-size property will become officially animatable soon, so this will become relevant.

Comment: If you aren't following the W3C specs, what are you following? W3C specs are built from implementation by the browser vendors and the browser vendors write the W3C specs.

Comment: Not me, I am following them, it's not about me. The browser vendors don't - referring to the period between the time a feature is introduced until it becomes official (or dies).

Comment: Amazing how Super Mario made it to the official bug report :)

Comment: @Shomz The W3C specifications are based on implementation, not invention. But just because a vendor introduces some new feature, it does not automatically mean it will make it into the spec. Hence, the purpose of vendor prefixes and, as example, the `<marquee>` element which has never been part of the HTML spec.

Comment: @vsync, yeah, they're really taking their time with this... Maybe it's fixed, but still hasn't made it to the stable release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this **was** a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616072

It's scheduled to be fixed in the next milestone, and this is the patch: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/8793a7bac4d2d56e38c8bd406920128e1ceb7a9a

Comment: Looks like the status of this patch has been set to "fixed", but now my background images are stretched instead. The vendor-specific prefix did fix the original problem. All was fine 1 or 2 days ago. Today, it's broken again. Removing the vendor-specific prefix reverts to the original problem. Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: I still don't have the fixed version of Chrome in my Ubuntu repo. What version do you have, @Julesfrog?

Comment: I have version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit) on Mac, which seems to be the latest. Regarding the issue (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616072) the status in the left column says that it was fixed on June 8. Using the vendor-specific prefix does fix the transition, but it stretches the image to fit the parent container. By removing the vendor-specific prefix, the transition breaks, but the background image (set at 110%) fits like it should.

Comment: Yup, that's the one I have (on Linux), and it seems that it works the same way as it did back when I've noticed the bug. The bug is closed on June 8th, but see the comments, seems like the patch still didn't make it to the stable version.

Comment: True. I missed that one. Maybe I didn't notice that the image was stretched until today, but I could have sworn that the vendor-specific prefix worked before. I'm hoping they will push the fix to the stable version soon.

Comment: Did you see the latest comments on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616072 ? Does it mean they won't be merging the patch with the stable version?

Comment: Saw it, but I'm still not sure what they mean by that.

Comment: @Julesfrog, more news: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616072#c26

Comment: That's good news! My portfolio is at stake here. I could redo it all in jQuery, but I'd rather not ;) Thanks for keeping me in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem and was able to fix it by changing my rules from

background-size: 115%;

to

background-size: 115% 115%;

Comment: Yes, they say in the bug report that it happens when you specify only one dimension.

Comment: The animation did work for me, but my images are still squashed. Bummer. Firefox and Safari work just fine.