# CSS3 animation with keyframes and background-size property not working in Chrome 51

Tags: css, css-animations

I had a piece of code similar to the one in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/e2tt2mao/203/). There are basically some keyFrames (0% and 100%) which sets the `background-size` property to 100%, while the keyFrame 50% sets that property to 50%.

```css
@keyframes imagebulger {
  0%,
  100% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 50% auto;
  }
}

div.hotspot {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: imagebulger 2s infinite !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot"></div>
```

That example worked as expected (performing the transition) in Chrome < 51, Firefox, IE 11 and so on. However, after the Chrome update (51.0.2704.63) it does not work anymore. I tried in Windows computer and in Linux computer and same result.

Somebody with that issue found a workaround? Otherwise I will post directly as a Chrome bug

Related with the issue [Background-size transitions in Chrome 51 - a bug or a feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545089/background-size-transitions-in-chrome-51-a-bug-or-a-feature), seems like it works using the prefix property but not without it, which does not makes sense at all.

[This version](http://jsfiddle.net/e2tt2mao/205/) will work, however I was forced to set the prefix `-webkit-` to the normal keyframes which probably will make this animation not work in some other browsers. I don't think that is an accepted solution.

Comment: Possible dupe (even though the other one doesn't have an answer) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545089/background-size-transitions-in-chrome-51-a-bug-or-a-feature

Comment: I can confirm that version 50 rendered the animation seamlessly, and then after updating to 51 it only snaps between the 0% keyframe and 100% - it doesn't animate.

Comment: I am also having this issue, and I believe Chrome has "optimised" it out for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

#### Workaround

Using both the standard `background-size` followed by `-webkit-background-size`, solves the problem ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/e2tt2mao/229/)).

```css
div.hotspot {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: imagebulger 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes imagebulger {
  0%, 100% {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 50% auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot"></div>
```