# Background size transition stopped working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have a background size transition which has suddenly stopped working in chrome and i cant figure out why. You can see what i mean if you hover over one of the category boxes on this page :

http://demo.elusivethemes.com/luxi/

It used to work fine but has now stopped. Any ideas why ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: This happened to me too...it worked a couple of weeks ago and stopped working recently. Here's a codepen of the issue: http://codepen.io/ericdjohnson/pen/NrRKRY

Comment: It's a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545089/background-size-transitions-in-chrome-51-a-bug-or-a-feature

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to the same issue today. I had `background-size: 300px;` and on `:hover`, `background-size:325px;`. On a whim, I tried setting both the height and width in the background-size, so `background-size: 300px 300px;` and the same for `:hover`, and it worked!

Not sure what you'll have to do with the way you're doing it, with the background-size as a percentage, but maybe this helps!

**Update**: It's a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=616072) in Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Use transform scale instead:

```
.cat-grid {
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.cat-grid:hover {
    background-size: 104%;
    transform: scale(.6);
}
```

Comment: That seems to scale the whole box and not just the background image

Answer (score 1):

Use Background Position and Background size to animate :
Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/shriharim/8tcbm6zw/

```
.thumbnail{
    background-image:url('http://www.quirkybyte.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Green-Nature-Trees-l-730x365.jpg');
    float:left;
    margin:1px;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-size:450px 450px;
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    background-size:550px 550px;
    background-position:-50px -50px;
    transition:all 0.5s ;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is the image boxes are dynamic so i have to use percentages. can it be done this way with percentages ?

Comment: Yes you can do that. change background size to percentage

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the transition in `.cat-grid` not `.cat-grid:hover`

```
webkit-transition: background-size .6s ease;
transition: background-size .6s ease;
```